# Checking properties for each file recursively in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I've been trying to make a bash script that starts at a folder, namely my home folder, then gets each file recursively and checks for some properties. Say I want to check to see if my files have a certain size and have text (not binary data) in them. It should take care of the special cases where the files are hidden or starting with a hyphen. This is what I came up with:

```
for i in $(cd "/home/user" && ls -aR);
do
    if [[ $(file ./"$i") == "./\"$i\": ASCII text" ]] && [[ $(du -b ./"$i" | grep -oE "[0-9]+") == "1015" ]]; then
        echo ./"$i"
    fi
done
```

I don't know how many subfolders there are, and I need it to echo the path of the files that meet the criteria. It works ok for files in /home/user/ but it doesn't seem to find (and thus check) the files in any subfolder. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate traversing the file tree from checking the individual files.

Start by writing a script which examines a single file and prints the file name to stdout if the file matches your criteria. Let's call this script *check_file*. Now use, for instance,

```
find /home/user -type f -exec check_file {} \;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I knew there must be a command that does this recursive search for me, I just didn't know which. For reference, the exact command that solved my problem: `find /home/user -type f -size 1015c`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are using `bash` 4 unless otherwise stated.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in /home/user/**/*:
    if [[ $(file -- "$f") != *": ASCII text" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    # This is the syntax for GNU stat; consult your manual for
    # other implementations
    size=$(stat -c %s -- "$f")
    if (( size != 1015 )); then
        continue
    fi

    echo "$f"
done
```